# Uncaught SyntaxError with Infinite Scroll wordpress plugin

Tags: jquery, wordpress, plugins, syntax-error

I have just moved hosts and now I'm getting this error on my site: http://craigmdennis.com/articles/ and I have no idea why.

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < infinitescroll.init.js.php:1
```

Can anyone shed any light on it?
Could it be a PHP extension that isn't turned on?

EDIT: When I click on the error in the console, it shows the following:

```
 Warning: require_once(../../../wp-load.php) [<a href='function.require-once'>function.require-once</a>]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in D:\Sites\Craig M Dennis\content\plugins\infinite-scroll\infinitescroll.init.js.php on line 5
```

and

```
 Fatal error: require_once() [<a href='function.require'>function.require</a>]: Failed opening required '../../../wp-load.php' (include_path='.;C:\php\pear') in D:\Sites\Craig M Dennis\content\plugins\infinite-scroll\infinitescroll.init.js.php on line 5
```

Before these is a `<br>` which seems to be causing the initial error in the console but there seems to be an underlying error.

Answer (score 0):

you might be using `<?php` twice. try removing one of them.

Comment: This then causes the error `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected string infinitescroll.init.js.php:9` so I don't think it's that.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, if it's a problem with the file path:

```
$c = 0;
$f = '';
while($c < 6) {
  $f .= '../';
  if(file_exists($f.'wp-load.php')) {
    include_once($f.'wp-load.php');
    break;
  }
  $c++;
}
```

Comment: This didn't fix it but I think you could be onto something as I have a custom content directory.

Comment: Ok so if I change the path to an absolute path the errors go away and I'm left with a 404 for a .gif and it still doesn't work. There are obviously some issues with the plugin when using a custom content directory. I have logged an issue in the github repo.